# undefined method for `require_all` in rails 5.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

i'm currently learning rails for my backend project. i can't figure out what was the cause of this error:

> config.ru:1:in `block in <main>': undefined method` require_all' for #Rack::Builder:0x000055b9e0066f68 (NoMethodError)

### config.ru file

```
require_all './app/controller/'
map('/map') {run TestmapController}
```

here's my current directory structure

```
app
├── channels
│   └── application_cable
│       ├── channel.rb
│       └── connection.rb
├── controllers
│   ├── api
│   │   └── moduletelefon
│   │       └── telefons_controller.rb
│   ├── application_controller.rb
│   ├── concerns
│   ├── serializers
│   │   └── telefon_serializer.rb
│   └── testmap_controller.rb
├── jobs
│   └── application_job.rb
├── mailers
│   └── application_mailer.rb
├── models
│   ├── application_record.rb
│   ├── concerns
│   └── telefon.rb
└── views
    └── layouts
        ├── mailer.html.erb
        └── mailer.text.erb
```

how is that `require_all` method cannot be found?
I'm using rails 5.2.6, ruby 2.5.8, and Sinatra 2.1.0.
I'm really new to this topic. please pardon me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

turns out config.ru is a rack file. so in order for me to initialize `testmap` controller is to require it into `rakefile` directly. but yes I still cannot use the `require_all` method anywhere else, even in the ruby file. but for now I did solve my problem